# How to extract the element from the dictionary without last item

Tags: python, dictionary

- I need to re-instantiate the dictionary without last element

Below are sample list and dictionary

List of Dictionary

```
[{'emptype': ['Manager'],
  'Designation': ['Developer'],
  'projecttype': ['temp']}]
```

Dictionary

```
{'emptype': ['Manager'],
  'Designation': ['Developer'],
  'projecttype': ['temp']}
```

How to extract the elements except last

Expected out from list of dictionary

```
[{'emptype': ['Manager'],
  'Designation': ['Developer']}]
```

Expected out from dictionary

```
 {'emptype': ['Manager'],
      'Designation': ['Developer']}
```

Comment: Suggest you to do it only in ordered dictionary... python built-in dict is not necessarily ordered so u cant expect any of the key-value pairs to stay consistently last or first

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop

Comment: But i m using python 3.8 so its  feauture now, no need of orderdict

Comment: Ok so it doesnt matter 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using map:

```
d = [{'emptype': ['Manager1'],
  'Designation': ['Developer1'],
  'projecttype': ['temp1']},
   {'emptype': ['Manager2'],
  'Designation': ['Developer2'],
  'projecttype': ['temp2']},
  {'emptype': ['Manager3'],
  'Designation': ['Developer3'],
  'projecttype': ['temp3']},
  {'emptype': ['Manager4'],
  'Designation': ['Developer4'],
  'projecttype': ['temp4']}]

def remove_last_key(item: dict):
    item.pop(
        list(item.keys())[-1]
    )
    return item

list(map(remove_last_key,d))
```

This was tested on Python 3.7.7 (and should work on 3.6+) - When working on dict based on their order, the Python version matters. You can read more here: [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)

EDIT:

In certain cases, list comprehension might provide some advantages in terms of performance and are considered clearer by some. In this case:

```
[remove_last_key(item) for item in d]
```

Comment: Is it compulsory to write the function, can we write without function, your code is working fine

Comment: @Maws You can still use the one liner i showed you...

Comment: I personally find that using a function improves readability, but it's not mandatory, as @adirabargil's answer demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_item(data):
    if type(data) is list:
        result = []
        for item in data:
            result.append(remove_item(item))
        return result
    elif type(data) is dict:
        data.pop(list(data.keys())[-1])
        return data
    return data
```

Comment: TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable

Comment: are you using python3?

Answer (score 0):

Here nice list comprehension in action:

```
  list_dicts = [dict(list(i.items())[:-1]) for i in list_dicts]
```

Comment: TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable

Comment: We needto see exactly how your list look like because it makes no sense...

Comment: take this as example `[{'emptype': ['Manager'],
  'Designation': ['Developer'],
  'projecttype': ['temp']}]`

Comment: I edited it , maybe try now... theissue i didnt cated the items to list...

Answer (score 0):

The basic operation for removing the last element of a dictionary `mydict` is `mydict.pop(list(mydict)[-1])`. If you have a list of dictionaries you can loop over them and apply the function to each dictionary.

mydict.keys()[-1] applies to python2